"candidate was blocked due to recitation" error API gemini
I'm making a automation bot in a site, using pupeteer and AI gemini API to solve the questions and return the solution for the app. Until now, all the requests I'm sending, no problems occurred, so the API connection is ok, but in one of the questions I tested, probably has any word unsafety, and the API return a error:

"candidate was blocked due to recitation"

I tried the safety configs but it don't nothing, what do I do?
const safe = {
"HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT": "BLOCK_NONE",
"HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH": "BLOCK_NONE",
"HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT": "BLOCK_NONE",
"HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT": "BLOCK_NONE",
};

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);
const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash" , safe });

//some code rest of application

... else if (typeOfQuestion === 'Subjetiva') {
const resposta = await model.generateContent(`resolva a seguinte questao, e retorne uma resposta apenas em texto, e sem simbolos muito especificos considerando que é uma resposta para escrever em livro didatico, somente se for uma materia que realmente necessite de simbolos, como matematica, quimica, etc.: ${questionHeader}, ${options}`)
console.log(resposta.response.text())
return resposta.response.text();

The response I get in this specific request is, I think the problem isn't in the pre-prompt, but in the question:
GoogleGenerativeAIResponseError: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Candidate was blocked due to RECITATION
   response: {
     candidates: [ { finishReason: 'RECITATION', index: 0 } ],
     usageMetadata: { promptTokenCount: 2437, totalTokenCount: 2437 },
     text: [Function (anonymous)],
     functionCall: [Function (anonymous)],
     functionCalls: [Function (anonymous)]   }

I tried put the safe settings, I'm the const safe = {...}; and setting in the model, but nothing changed.

have you read this

If you "think the problem isn't in the pre-prompt, but in the question", then you should provide the question.

Does the Gemini prompt require accessing copyrighted material? Edit your post to provide enough details to reproduce your problem.

Google is aware of the issue and it has been open on google's bug tracker  since March 2024: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/331677495
There is also discussion here on an issue raised on the javascript sdk's repo: https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-js/issues/138
It's something google added intentionally 1 to prevent copyright material being returned verbatim (ala the NYT openai fiasco 2) so they dialled up the "recitation" control (the act repeating training data).
Here are some quotes from the bug tracker page:

I got this error by just asking "Who is Google?"


We're encountering recitation errors even with basic tutorials on application development.
When bootstrapping a Spring Boot app, we're flagged for the pom.xml being too similar to some blog posts.


This error is a deal breaker... It occurs hundreds of times a day for our users and massively degrades their UX.


I had this same problem, almost half of my request were returning the 'RECITATION' finish reason. I noticed I was using the model "gemini-1.5-flash", and just switching to the model "gemini-1.5-flash-002" seems to have solved the problem.
